# Determine field belonging to django many to many link

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have 4 hypothetical models:

```
class Basea(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=30)
    type = models.ManyToManyField('Type', blank=True, related_name='types', db_table=u'test_basea_type')

class Baseb(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=30)
    type = models.ManyToManyField('Type', blank=True, related_name='types', db_table=u'test_baseb_type')

class Basec(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=30)
    type = models.ManyToManyField('Type', blank=True, related_name='types', db_table=u'test_basec_type')

class Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("Name", max_length=30, unique=True)
    baseas = ManyToManyField_NoSyncdb(Basea, blank=True, related_name='type_baseas',  db_table=u'test_basea_type')
    basebs = ManyToManyField_NoSyncdb(Baseb, blank=True, related_name='type_basebs',  db_table=u'test_baseb_type')
    basecs = ManyToManyField_NoSyncdb(Basec, blank=True, related_name='type_basecs',  db_table=u'test_basec_type')
```

I'm creating a new Type, and I want to attach a many-to-many link after the new Type object is saved.  In my view, this works just fine:

```
if form.is_valid(): # All validation rules pass
    new_obj = form.save(commit=False)
    # Do some stuff 
    new_obj.save()
    new_obj.baseas.add(link_object.id) #link_object pulled earlier in the code
```

So I'll have a link_object that's either Basea, Baseb, or Basec. What code could I use to change the last line:

```
    new_obj.baseas.add(link_object.id)
```

such that the field corresponds to the correct object type?  So if link_object was from Baseb, the code should perform the function:

```
    new_obj.basebs.add(link_object.id)
```

How can that field name be defined more generically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for [GenericForeignKey](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.generic.GenericForeignKey).